# postfix virtualdomain - message bouncing - unknown user error in maillog

Tags: postfix-mta

I have configured the virtual domain in postfix 2.x

Please check the configuration below:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = ghhdomain.com, krdomain.com, murugeshdomain.com
#setup virtual domains mailbase for mailboxes
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail

#create lookup file that maps email addresses to respective mailboxes

virtual_mailbox_map = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

#who will be the owner of the mailbox file
virtual_uid_maps = static:503
virtual_gid_maps = static:503"
```

added to /etc/postfix/virtual

```
info@ghhdomain.com   ghhdomain/info
info@krdomain.com    krdomain/info"

done postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
```

while testing

```
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.murugeshdomain.com ESMTP Postfix
ehlo ghhdomain.com
250-mail.murugeshdomain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

And.. When I do mail from: info@ghhdomain.com  and rcpt to:info@ghhdomain.com
I get the enter code hereror in the log.

```
bounced - unknown user "info@ghhdomain.com
```

What is that missing, 
TIA
Hari

Answer (score 0):

Here you use the virtual_mailbox_map = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual, ie you use the virtual alias file for the virtual mailbox map. You are not suppose to do this.
So please use different files for virtual alias and virtual mailbox

So you can use,
    virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
    virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

```
/etc/postfix/vmailbox:
info@ghhdomain.com   ghhdomain/info
info@krdomain.com    krdomain/info
```

you can verify more details in this [link](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html)

Answer (score 0):

## make aliases for local accounts/users

in **/etc/postfix/main.cf** edit :

```
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual-alias-maps.cf 
                     regexp:/etc/postfix/local-users-aliases
   # ---- put everything on same line ---------
```

Now Postfix will build aliases list from mysql table (you can use and/or hash from file ...  postfix accept a list of sources) and using regular expresion from file

write **local-users-aliases**

```
echo "/^(webmaster|www|ftp|postmaster|root|MAILER-DAEMON|abuse)/ u_mail@u_domain" > 
                  /etc/postfix/local-users-aliases
```

after `/etc/init.d/postfix restart` any mail sent to postmaster fro ex will go to u_mail@u_domain